# A series about a planet called Duncan

Tags: story-identification

People from Earth travel through a quantum space fold to colonize other new planets for resources. One is named Duncan after the first guy killed there. Humans survive in a hostile environment. Creatures called questrals (maybe) bite and eventually form trinary DNA in humans. The Earth corporation technically owns the planet but the original survivors have established their own free colony.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Is this a TV series, a book series, a webnovel series?  When and where did you watch/read it?

Answer (score 3):

Could this be *[Cries of the Chosen](https://books.apple.com/es/book/cries-of-the-chosen/id466465823)* by A.S. Lewis?

There's mention of a planet called Duncan III and a third DNA strand that controls telekinesis.

> ... Mark and Kiiyla flee in a shuttleship and avoid capture. They settle on a non-allied planet called Duncan III where they fall in love and eventually get married. They hide there happily for three years before the Rell discovers their whereabouts. He sends his people to bring back his son and kill the girl. They capture Mark and disguise his abduction as a terrorist bombing. Kiiyla hears that her husband is dead, but she is given no time to mourn as her assassin is in her house. Kiiyla narrowly escapes and is now under the protection of the local authorities. Kiiyla, not one to live in a cage or on the run, is easily persuaded by a young woman named Ayanna Mangai to join the UCIP Marine Corps.